# Creation of workspace

Tags: eclipse

We have the Headless (Command Line) Plugins developed in eclipse.During executing these Headless (Command Line) Plugins "workspace" folder along with .metadata folder is created at the location where the product ".exe" is present.So how can we prevent creation of the workspace folder for Headless (Command Line) Plugins.

Comment: find the update in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-data @none` argument to a headless RCP to specify that no workspace should be created. You can also set the environment variable `osgi.instance.area=@none` for this.

See the [Eclipse runtime options help](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) for more details.

Comment: but if we are running the headless plugin from command prompt using eclipse.exe it might still create a workspace because calling the eclipse.exe might need the workspace .meta data to load all the OSGI classes

Comment: With @none the workspace will never be created - you would get an error if something tries to use it. You can specify a configuration area for shared metadata see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html)